# servlet printing null values to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a web form in a jsp that is supposed to get values from a servlet, but it is printing out null values.  I am including the code for the jsp and for the servlet below.  Can anyone show me how to fix the code below so that it prints out the values from the request object instead of printing null?

Here is the code for my.jsp:

```
<jsp:useBean id="errors" scope="request" type="java.util.Map" class="java.util.HashMap" />
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width=302>
            </td>
            <td width=250>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=150 align="right">tha: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="tha" value="c3t" size="15" />
                            <%if (errors.containsKey("tha")) {out.println("<span class=\"error\">" + errors.get("tha") + "</span>");}  
                            else{out.println(request.getParameter("tha"));}%>  
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=150 align="right">min: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="min" value="0" size="15" />
                            <% if (errors.containsKey("min")) {out.println("<span class=\"error\">" + errors.get("min") + "</span>");}  
                            else{out.println(request.getParameter("min"));}%>  
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=150 align="right">max: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="max" value="2*pi" size="15" />
                        <% if (errors.containsKey("max")) {out.println("<span class=\"error\">" + errors.get("max") + "</span>");}
                        else{out.println(request.getParameter("max"));}%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align="right">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit-button" value="Click To Plot" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And here is the code for the servlet:

```
public class PlotPolarServlet extends HttpServlet{
    private RequestDispatcher jsp;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
       ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
       jsp = context.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/my.jsp");
    } 

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        jsp.forward(req, resp);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{
        Map<String, String> errors = validate(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()){  
            jsp.forward(req, resp);
            return;
        }
        resp.sendRedirect("my");
    }

    public static Map<String, String> validate(HttpServletRequest req){
        HashMap<String, String> errors = new HashMap<String, String>();
        req.setAttribute("errors", errors);
        String tha = req.getParameter("tha");
        if (tha == null || tha.trim().length() == 0){
            errors.put("tha", "tha required.");
        }
        String min = req.getParameter("min");
        if (min == null || min.trim().length() == 0){
            errors.put("min", "min required.");
        }
        String max = req.getParameter("max");
        if (max == null || max.trim().length() == 0){
            errors.put("max", "max required.");
        }
        return errors;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote : Get rid of that instance variable and use JSTL/EL in JSP !

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Can you be more specific? Suggest actual line(s) to add/remove?

Comment: @CodeMed All of them that aren't JSTL/EL.

Comment: Have you verified that `validate` is running?

Comment: @CodeMed Your code works as expected, I've updated my answer to explain what is happening. I originally misunderstood where you were getting `null`. The issue, however, still comes from the `sendRedirect`.

Answer (score 2):

I originally misread your question. The issue is when parameters are input correctly, not when there is an error. The `else` part of this code

```
<% if (errors.containsKey("min")) {out.println("<span class=\"error\">" + errors.get("min") + "</span>");}  
else{out.println(request.getParameter("min"));}%>
```

can't print anything but `null` because, in this request, there are no parameters with those keys.

A [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) returns a 302 HTTP status code which would make your browser send a new HTTP request to the location described by the String parameter. The request **parameters** would not be in the new request (the request context/scope is cleared once the request is handled). You would need to put them in the session attributes.

```
/*
   for every parameter, put it in the session attributes
*/
req.getSession(true).setAttribute("myParam", req.getParameter("myParam"));
resp.sendRedirect("my");
```

This is known as flash scope and flash attributes and it can be implemented as explained [here](http://kumarnvm.blogspot.ca/2012/07/implementing-flash-scope-in-java-web.html) with a servlet `Filter`. You basically store attributes you want to reuse between 2 requests, then delete them.

**As for Edit:**

Unless you've copy-pasted the code in your edit incorrectly

```
<td><input type="text" name="yX" value="cx" size="15" />
    <%if (errors.containsKey("yX")) {   // errors doesn't contain yX as a Key, it contains imageParam1
         out.println("<span class=\"error\">" + errors.get("yX") + "</span>");
    }else{out.println(request.getParameter("yX"));}%> // will print the value of the request parameter with key yX
</td>
```

you're `POST`ing a parameter called `yX`, but looking for `imageParam`. Your `doPost()` method will create an `errors` request attribute and then `forward` (instead of `sendRedirect`).

```
errors.put("imageParam1", "imageParam1 required.");
...
if (!errors.isEmpty()){
    jsp.forward(req, resp);
    return;
}
```

not `yX`. Therefore, the `else` gets evaluated and the parameter exists since it's the same request.

**MORE EXPLANATION**

In your `my` example:

1. If you didn't enter a required field, the `doPost()` method gets called, the `errors` map is populated and your code does `jsp.forward(req, resp);` which uses the same request and the parameters are available when the jsp is rendered.
2. If you entered all the required fields, the `doPost()` is called and `resp.sendRedirect("my");` is executed. This causes your browser to send a new GET HTTP request with new parameters/attributes. This causes the `doGet()` to be called to process the new request, which forwards to your jsp. The original request parameters aren't included in this request so there is nothing to show, thus `null` when `else{out.println(request.getParameter("min"));` gets rendered.

In your `myother` example, because of the difference between the `<input>` parameter name in the jsp and the parameter name you're looking for in the servlet, you're getting completely irrelevant results which I've explained above. Disregard this servlet. It is not doing what you thought it was doing correctly.

Comment: thanks for letting me know I was wrong :) . Upvote for correct answer :)

Comment: @PrasadKharkar I would've made a comment too, but you deleted before I could.

Comment: @CodeMed Change the scope in your `jsp:useBean`. The attribute is now in the session. And don't use Java code in your jsps, it's bad practice.

Comment: @CodeMed You would change it to `session`, as the `errors` attribute would now be in the session. You could also just use `${errors}` with [`el`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). EL processor looks in the request attributes, then in session attributes, then in application attributes, returning the first one it finds.

Comment: @CodeMed The problem is as I described it in my answer. You are using `resp.sendRedirect("my");`. In your other project, you might be using `RequestDispatcher#forward(req,resp)`. They have different purposes.

Comment: @CodeMed This is all explained in my answer. Let me add some more, 3 mins. The link assumes you know how to setup a filter. Use google or search this site, it's a simple web.xml setup.

Comment: @CodeMed I suggest you read up on the difference between `sendRedirect` and `forward` and then about HTTP status codes.

Comment: @CodeMed You would know what to change if you read the question carefully. I'm not trying to give you a solution, I'm trying to help you understand how servlets work. You have all these (my links, google, SO) resources at your disposal. The solution depends on what you need. If all you want is to show the entered parameters, get rid of the `if` check in `doPost()` and do `jsp.forward(req, resp)` in all cases. Except for the original request (a GET without request parameters), you will see actual values in your status fields. **Read** because you won't understand next time this happens.

Comment: @CodeMed My last comment has the code change you need to get it to do what you want. I don't like spelling things out. You should be able to find an answer with my explanation of why you're seeing that servlet behavior.

Comment: @CodeMed Is the result what you we're trying to get?